# VBA macro to copy a list of cells one at a time into another sheet for API process

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am new to building macros but think what i am trying to do is possible and will make life so much easier. I am trying to create a macro that will copy a list of 100 cells in column A of sheet one one at a time into SHeet Detailed for processing, then copying the output from sheet Detailed (after API's run) back into sheet 1 next to cell A3. Then i want it to move onto A4 and follow the same process.

I am trying to build a macro that will copy cell A3 (which is a list of 100 cells below each other in column A) from sheet one, then paste it into $A$1 in Sheet Detailed. after the API's run, i want it to copy $C$21, $C$22,$D$25 (etc another 5 fixed cells of output) back into Sheet one into row 1 adjacent to A3 so that it is B3, D3, E3. and so forth.

Then i want it to move to cell A4 from sheet one, then paste it into $A$1 in Sheet Detailed, let the API's run, copy $C$21, $C$22,$D$25 back into Sheet one into row 1 adjacent to A4 so that it is B4, D4, E4. and so forth.

I am not even sure which terminology to use here.

What I have so far is:

```
Sub a()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For I = 3 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & I).Copy Sheets("Detailed").Range("A1")
        Call Wait_Fo_API()
        Sheets("Detailed").Calculate
        .Range("B" & I).Value = Sheets("Detailed").Range("C21").Value
        .Range("D" & I).Value = Sheets("Detailed").Range("C22").Value
        .Range("E" & I).Value = Sheets("Detailed").Range("D25").Value
        ' add rest of output cells
    Next I

End With

End Sub


Sub Wait_Fo_API()

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:02:00")
```

Your assistance will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Sub Start()

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Detailed")

i = 2

woopi2

End Sub

Sub woopi2()

ws1.Range("A" & i).Copy
ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

If ws1.Range("A" & i) = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Wait_For_Copy
End If

End Sub

Sub Wait_For_Copy()

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "Copy_Values"

End Sub

Sub Copy_Values()

    ws2.Range("C25").Copy
    ws1.Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ws2.Range("C23").Copy
    ws1.Range("D" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
i = i + 1

woopi2

End Sub
```